# How can I provide both a ground truth and examples of Q&A to my OpenAI model?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-openai

[OpenAI documentation about factual responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/completions#factual-responses) indicates it's possible to give my model a ground truth but I don't get how to do so.
I would like to provide a long documentation, for instance, thousand wikipedia articles, then provide examples of Questions and Answers. These Q&A would teach my model the expected format of the answer and to tell that it doesn't know, when it hasn't any response based on the provided articles.

[In the API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/openai/how-to/prepare-dataset) I only see that I can provide a dataset of Q&A but no way to provide ground truth data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OpenAI documentation itself it’s recommended to use embeddings instead of fine-tuning for knowledge. This is recommended from OpenAI.

Fine-tuning is not knowledge. You can find the message (from OpenAI) below in their cookbook.

Note: To answer questions based on text documents, we recommend the procedure in [Question Answering using Embeddings](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/Question_answering_using_embeddings.ipynb).

https://community.openai.com/t/fine-tuning-myths-openai-documentation/133608/1